# Is it usage of passive form of past perfect tense : "She had been born with a congenital heart problem"

Tags: past-perfect

Is it usage of passive form of past perfect tense:

> “She had been born with a congenital heart problem”

I got this sentence structure from Murakami's short story. Please explain to me.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect is used to indicate an action that happened before another past action. The quotation that you have given is insufficient to determine what the birth preceded.

Sometimes in written English, long passages may be written in the past perfect to recount a whole series of actions that preceded an action.

The fact that the verb is in the passive merely reflects that the passive form is the way that termination from residing *in utero* is described in English. (The usage reflects the reality: it is the mother who does the work.)